# How can I change isReadable of imported DDS images?

Tags: unity, textures

I'm importing DDS textures from editor scripts and I need to access the `GetPixels()` method from each imported texture to check if the image have transparent pixels.

When importing the images by just creating the file inside the Unity project *Assets* folder from an editor script, the asset will have its `isReadable` property set to `false` which will cause an exception when executing `GetPixels()` (because `isReadble` is false).

The `isReadble` property is `readonly` from the `Texture2D` class. I read somewhere that I could use its `TextureImporter` class to set the property to `true` and re import the asset through `AssetDatabase.ImportAsset()`. The problem is that the importer used to import DDS images seems to be an implementation of `IHVImageFormatImporter` and the `isReadable` property there is `readonly` too.

As far as I checked `IHVImageFormatImporter` can't be converted to `TextureImporter`. So I left the question: in this case, how can I modify `isReadable` for imported DDS images?

Or maybe there is another way to be able to read those images from code without throwing an exception?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44733841/950488) or [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/56583/33287) address your question?

Comment: First link did the job. Ty!